# How to retrieve Couchbase auto-failover interval

Tags: couchbase

As per my current understanding, there is a minimum delay of 30 secs for Couchbase auto-failover. During this interval it is expected for client application to get Network failure during read and write operations. Client application need to handle these scenario.

We intend to catch this error and sleep for time till couchbase has intiated auto-failover. We are not able to find any API (C SDK ) to retrieve the configured interval.

1. Is there any API in C sdk that can return this interval so that client can retry after this?

Thank you in advance for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible with an API call, but I will keep looking. In the meantime you can certainly get this using the REST API. Here is the information from the Couchbase documentation:

http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/REST/rest-cluster-autofailover-settings.html